# What is wrong in this python print statement with multiple joins?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of colors and I am trying to print all the colors in one line except the last color.
I want to append '&' before the last element

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple']
print(', '.join(colors[-1:])' & '.join(colors[:-1]))
```

Expecting output:
red, green, blue & purple

Comment: You have two separate `.join()` expressions, that are individually valid (although neither one is joining exactly the items you seem to want them to).  However, you've just run the two expressions together, which makes a syntactically invalid mess.  You either need to separate the expressions with a comma (making them two separate items for the `print()`, or with a `+` to concatenate them into a single string.  Try `', '.join(colors[:-1]) + ' & ' + colors[-1]`.

Comment: your print expression is wrong, dots and single quotes are misplaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the correct statement in your code :

`print(', '.join(colors[:-1]) + ' & ' + colors[-1])`

This should work as well:

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple']
print('{}, & {}'.format(', '.join(colors[:-1]), colors[-1]))
```

https://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php